# Using UIPageViewController in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have UIPageViewController placed in UIScrollView, pageview scrolling in horizontal direction, scrollview in vertical. The scrollview works fine, but when I swipe horizontal in pageview area nothing happend.

[image: UIPageViewController in UIScrollView]

I tried add to every scrollview gesture recognizers requireGestureRecognizerToFail gesture recognizers from pageview, but this only off scrolling on pageview area:

```
  UIScrollView sv;  
    for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            sv = (UIScrollView*)view;
        }
    }
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in sv.gestureRecognizers) {
            for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerForFail in self.scrollview.gestureRecognizers) {
                [gestureRecognizerForFail requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
            }
    }
```

The every controllers in pageview works fine, when I change them by the buttons in scrollview, but the swipe doesn't work.